# Passing parameters to method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have js code where I pass data  to repo method via parameters.

Here is repo method:

```
public List<SpeedLimitViewModel> GetSpeedData(decimal imei, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        using (TraxgoDB ctx = new TraxgoDB())
        {
            List<SpeedLimitViewModel> alldata = new List<SpeedLimitViewModel>();
            var alllogs = ctx.Logging.OrderByDescending(x => x.LogID).ToList();

            for (int i = 1; i < alllogs.Count; i++)
            {
                alldata.Add(new SpeedLimitViewModel
                {
                    Imei= alllogs[i].Imei,
                    Latitude2 = alllogs[i].Latitude,
                    Longitude2 = alllogs[i].Longitude,
                    Speed = alllogs[i].Speed
                });
            }
            return alldata;
        }


    }
```

And I call this method in controller like this:

```
  public JsonResult SpeedData()
    {
        var speeddata = repoEntities.GetSpeedData();
        return Json(speeddata.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

But I have error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'imei' of 'ReportsRepositoryEntities.GetSpeedData(decimal, DateTime, DateTime)'    Traxgo.TrackerWeb   C:\Users\EugeneSukhomlyn\Source\Workspaces\TraxgoWeb\Traxgo.TrackerWeb\Controllers\ReportsController.cs 94  Active

Where is my problem?

Comment: Your method has 3 arguments - you need to pass values for them when you call that method (although you never seem to use them, so you could just delete them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public JsonResult SpeedData(decimal imei, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        var speeddata = repoEntities.GetSpeedData(imei, start, end);
        return Json(speeddata.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: and in method, I need to leave parameters too?

Comment: In repo method, no need to change anything, But if you call controller method from View, you need to pass these 3 parameters (imei, start, end).

Comment: Yes, I call controller method from View and method in controller call method in repo.

Comment: Could you please try again? It should be working fine now. If still not working, please drop your code in View how you call controller.

Answer (score 3):

Your method looks like that:

```
GetSpeedData(decimal imei, DateTime start, DateTime end)
```

Yet you are calling it like that:

```
GetSpeedData()
```

Also I don't see you are using `imei` or `start` or `end` anywhere in your method, so you should probably remove them from your method definition

So you should pass parameters to your function, probably from your controller method like so:

```
public JsonResult SpeedData(decimal imei, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var speeddata = repoEntities.GetSpeedData(imei, start, end);
    return Json(speeddata.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Or maybe the parameters will not come from controller method, but from somewhere else - does not matter, in your current design you will have to pass defined parameters to your GetSpeedData function.

Or you can define your function like that (using optional parameters):

```
public List<SpeedLimitViewModel> GetSpeedData(decimal imei = 0, DateTime start = new DateTime(), DateTime end = new DateTime())
{
}
```

And you will be able to call it even by calling `GetSpeedData()` (all the parameters will have values provided as default values for optional parameters)

Comment: I will use parameters in method, so I need it in repo method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove paramteres for your functions or you need to set default values in method definition like Paweł mentioned, or finally you can overload your method defitinion to the version with and without parameters.